# Preview PDFs with helm-bibtex

Tags: helm, docview, pdf-tools

I use `helm-bibtex` to navigate and manage my bibtex database. Each entry is linked to a PDF.

I am looking for a way to see a live preview of each pdf, while scanning through my helm completion window and marking entries that I want to read, take notes on, etc.

Alternatively, integration with QuickLook (I'm on a Mac) would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look into helm's persistent actions. Basically allows you to execute an action (like opening the PDF) without ending the helm session.  If your helm-bibtex is setup to use pdf-tools for viewing PDFs (see `helm-bibtex-pdf-open-function`), you're basically good to go.